# How can i check a checkbox in first span from the script in the second span?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, checkbox, thymeleaf

I need a check box created with attribute checked in it after the checkbox created..
I created a checked checkbox in the second span using thymeleaf

Thymeleaf code:

```
<span th:if="${field.fieldtype == 'CHECK'}">
    <input class="check" name="checkbox" type="checkbox"
           th:id="@{${field.value}}"  th:value="${record.id}"/>
</span>
<span th:if="${field.fieldtype == 'CHECK'}">
    <div th:each="prd ,iterStat : ${prdList}" th:remove="tag">
            <div th:if="${field.value}==${prd.Name}" th:remove="tag">
                <!-- <input class="check" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="true"
                    th:id="@{${field.value}}" th:value="${record.id}" /> --> //appends an extra checkbox with already existing one but with checked attr
                <script type="text/javascript">//script code to check the unchecked check box</script>
            </div>
    </div>
 </span>
```

My generated html code looks something like this,

```
<td>
<span> 
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="NAME" name="checkbox" class="check">
</span>
<span>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('checkme');
        $(this).closest('input').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', true);
     });
    </script>
</span>
</td>
<td>
    <span> ..checkbox.. </span>
    <span> ..script.. </span>
</td>
<td>
    <span> ..checkbox.. </span>
    <span>  </span>//in some conditon script not created so leave the checkbox unchecked
</td>
<td>
    <span> ..checkbox.. </span>
    <span> ..script.. </span>
</td>
```

I need to check the checkbox in the first span from the script in the second span only if
it has a script in it..How can i do this..[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/jx43j/)

thanks..

Comment: `$('span').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: @palaѕн that code works but it checks all the checkboxes..but i need that code to work only where the second span has the script then check the input box in the first span just above the span the script is inserted into..